# Reducing estimation noise from several random draws

Tags: estimation, random-generation

I was reading a paper in connection with preparing my thesis defense, where I stumbled upon a methodologic choice that I cannot fully understand.

For context, assume a group of 16 firms exists. The authors have restricted their group sizing of their analysis to 10 firms. In order to "reduce" the 16 firms to 10, the authors explicitly state:

> To reduce estimation noise in our random sampling of firms, we
>   simulate 500 draws of random firms and all results are based on the
>   average of these draws.

The purpose of establishing a group of 10 firms, is to take an average of some accounting variable and apply it to a "similar" firm. However, while I understand how they've done it - I am not sure how simulating 500 random draws eliminates estimation noise? Since the draws are random, wouldn't it be equal to simply simulating a draw 1 time?